# Recibir datos post en node js express js

Tags: nodejs, express, post

Llevo días tratando de recibir datos enviados mediante formulario post y siempre me sale el mensaje "undefined" cuando trato de usar req.body. Alguna idea de porqué esta mal? soy nuevo en node js. Este es mi código:

```
router.post('/save', function(req, res, next) {
    var titulo = req.body.titulo;
    console.log(titulo);
});
```

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, que tal, este es mi código:
router.post('/save', function(req, res, next) {
    var titulo = req.body.titulo;
    console.log(titulo);
}); 
por ahora solo estoy haciendo prueba con uno de los inputs del formulario pero me aparece el mensaje "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que necesites incorporar `body-parser`

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Y configurarlo para leer datos POST de un formulario

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Luego usar el codigo que intentas utilizar

```
router.post('/save', function(req, res, next) {
    var titulo = req.body.titulo;
    console.log(titulo);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de mucha ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Con express puedes realizar:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json();
```

Sin necesidad de mas librerias.

Comment: Sin bien tu respuesta es una alternativa al uso de librerías adicionales a express, considero que es una respuesta parcial, pues el OP hace mención a poder hacer uso de la información a través del verbo `POST`, cosa que no se menciona en tu respuesta. Considera [edit] tu respuesta y agregar la información para que tu respuesta sea una respuesta completa. Puedes ver [answer] para mejores referencias.

Comment: Adicionalmente, te invito a realizar el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Bienvenido a [es.so].

Comment: Podrías agregar el ejemplo completo, si comparamos como se muestra acá [Express.js express.json() Function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-express-json-function/) `app.use(express.json();` <- faltó un parentesis. Parece facilitar/habilitar el que luego puedas usar `req.body.titulo` sino lanzaría el error que presentan en la pregunta.